# How to enable reflection for message created with DynamicMessageFactory?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c, protocol-buffers-3

Code that creates a message:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Message> MessagePacker::BuildMessage() const {
  google::protobuf::DynamicMessageFactory factory;
  Message* msg = factory.GetPrototype(descriptor_)->New();
  return std::unique_ptr<Message>(msg);
}
```

Test code:

```cpp
  MessagePacker packer(HelloRequest::descriptor());
  auto result = packer.BuildMessage();
  ASSERT_NE(result, nullptr);
  std::cerr << result->GetReflection() << std::endl;
```

Reflection is null. Can't get field values, can't do `DebugString`.

How can I enable the reflection?

This returns a non-null pointer: `HelloRequest().GetReflection()`